# UIView to to Image when I press button

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm a newbie, and I'm practicing. I have an app with 3 imageView (Create Avatar App). I want that when I press the button, an image is saved, with the 3 custom imageview. The code I have is the following:

```
    @IBAction func saveImageMen (_ sender: Any) {
           
    
            
           }
   extension UIView{
         func createTransparentImage () -> UIImage {
             let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default ()
             renderFormat.opaque = false
             self.isOpaque = false
             self.layer.isOpaque = true
             self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
             self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
             let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer (size: bounds.size, format: renderFormat)
             return renderer.image {
                 (context) in
                 layer.render (in: context.cgContext)
             }
         }
    }
```

I don't know how to run this extension when the button is pressed

Comment: which view you want to save ?

Comment: I want to save a UIView that has 3 Image View, when i press the save button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to render an image, you can create extension for UIImageView as this is derived from UIView something below, this will render image on click of the button:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
 }

@IBAction func renderImage(_ sender: Any) {
   imageView.createTransparentImage()
}

}

extension UIImageView {
 func createTransparentImage () {
     let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default ()
     renderFormat.opaque = false
     self.isOpaque = false
     self.layer.isOpaque = true
     self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
     self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
     let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer (size: bounds.size, format: renderFormat)
     self.image = renderer.image {
         (context) in
         layer.render (in: context.cgContext)
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it is an extension of UIView class and you can call a function with an instance of the class so here you go:

```
UIView().createTransparentImage()
```

This will return the image so user it something like above:

```
let image  = UIView().createTransparentImage()
```

Comment: but it doesn't work for me. "Invalid redeclaration of 'createTransparentImage()'" I have the code like this.
`code`
 @IBAction func SaveImage (_ sender: Any) {
           
        parentViewImage.createTransparentImage()
            //parentViewImage is the view that i want captured
           }
        
         }


     extension UIView{
         func createTransparentImage () -> UIImage {
             let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default ()
...
`code`

Comment: make sure you have created the extension only one time and outside of any class scopes